# neo4j: List of ints from plain string representation

Tags: neo4j, cypher

### Context

I would like to read from a csv-file into my database and create nodes and connections. For the to be created order nodes, one of the fields to read is a stuffed list of Products (relational key), i.e. looks like this `"[123,456,789]"` where the numbers are the product ids.

Now reading the data into the db I have no problem to create nodes for the Orders and the Products; going over another iteration I now want to create the edges by kind of unwinding the list of products in the Order and linking to the according products.

Best would be if I could at creation time of the Order-nodes convert the string containing the list into a list of ints, so that a simple loop over these values and matching the Product-nodes would do the trick (also for storage efficiency this would be better).

### Problem

However I cannot figure out how to convert the said string into the said format of a list containing ints. All my attempts with coming up with a cypher for this failed miserably. I will post some of them below, starting from the string `l`:

```
WITH '[123,456,789]' as l
WITH split(replace(replace(l,'[',''),']',''),',') as s
UNWIND s as ss
COLLECT(toInteger(ss) ) as k 
return k

WITH '[123,456,789]' as l
WITH split(replace(replace(l,'[',''),']',''),',') as s, [] as k
FOREACH(ss IN s| SET k = k + toInteger(ss) )
return k
```

both statements failing.

### EDIT

I have found a partial solution, I am however not quite satisfied with as it applied only to my task at hand, but is not a solution to the more general problem of this list conversion.

I found out that one can create an empty list as an property of a node, which can be successively updated:

```
CREATE (o:Order {k: []})
WITH o, '[123,456]' as l
WITH o, split(replace(replace(l,'[',''),']',''),',') as s
FOREACH(ss IN s | SET o.k= o.k + toInteger(ss) )
RETURN o.k
```

strangly this will only work on properties of nodes, but not on bound variables (see above)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `substring()` to trim out the brackets at the start and the end.

This approach will allow you to create a list of the ints:

```
WITH '[123,456,789]' as nums
WITH substring(nums, 1, size(nums)-2) as nums
WITH split(nums, ',') as numList
RETURN numList
```

You can of course perform all these operations at once, and then UNWIND the subsequent list, convert them to ints, and match them to products:

```
WITH '[123,456,789]' as nums
UNWIND split(substring(nums, 1, size(nums)-2), ',') as numString
WITH toInteger(numString) as num
MATCH (p:Product {id:num})
...
```

EDIT

If you just want to convert this to a list of integers, you can use [list comprehension](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/lists/#cypher-list-comprehension) to do this once you have your list of strings:

```
WITH '[123,456,789]' as nums
WITH split(substring(nums, 1, size(nums)-2), ',') as numStrings
WITH [str in numStrings | toInteger(str)] as nums
...
```

Comment: i see that you simplified the string-trimming, but the list that is returned by your first statement is a list of strings, not as required a list of ints, so you delay the conversion with another with statement. That is fine, still I really would like to see, how I would need to fixup the my minimal statements in the 'Problem' section above, to make this thing work.

Comment: You may consider writing your own function. imho, a clear function name helps keeping the cypher query readable

In my "Learning Neo4j 3.x, second edition", there is a chapter on that

Comment: @MarcelZoll If you just want to convert to a list of strings to a list of ints, I updated my above answer.

Answer (score 7):

Since the input string looks like a valid JSON object, you can simple use the [`apoc.convert.fromJsonList`](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_from_tojson) function from the [`APOC library`](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures):

```
WITH "[123,456,789]" AS l
RETURN apoc.convert.fromJsonList(l)
```